# JASO MA confusion

Tags: motorcycle, oil

Motorcycle owner's manuals say to use "THEIR" oil, mine say nothing of JASO MA anything. So....The question remains:  bikes with joint clutch and engine use JASO MA, or MA2 ?

Comment: Hi and welcome.  It's better to not start a post with (or even include) a rant.  Just post an easy-to-understand question.  Can you provide references for your examples of "owners manuals" that fit your concern?

Answer (score 5):

Oils classified as JASO MA are subdivided into three different categories - MA, MA1 and MA2 depending on their properties:

[image: JASO MA Oil properties]

[Source](https://www.oilspecifications.org/articles/JASO_MA_JASO_MB.php)

So if all the listed characteristics fall under either MA1 or MA2 then they are classified as that - if they meet some of MA1 and some of MA2 then they would be just listed as JASO MA.

So if your bike's manual specifies "MA" you can use either MA, MA1 or MA2 - if instead it specified MA1 or MA2  then you won't be able to use "just MA" but will have to get the exact variant specified.